# How to change the return value of p.getProperty("os.arch");

Tags: java, jvm

I need a workaround a 64 bit problem. Where an interface I am using will only allow "x86" and my architecture is "x86_64".

The external references I am using (JAR File Classes only) will only allow "x86"

How can i achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Can you please post a code example? If the return type is a string you could simple cut the "_64" off if that is what you want.

Comment: I am dealing with a JAR file (Classes only) Where there is a check at the beginning that the arch should be "x86". That is why I want to temporarily change the property of "os.arch" from x86_64 to x86

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "p.setProperty". I assume you're referring to the system property "os.arch"?

You can use

`System.setProperty ("os.arch","x86");`

However, if the code you're using really does rely on the architecture being x86 and not x86_64, then fooling it in this way may not be helpful. In that case, you could consider using the -d32 switch:

`java -d32 ...`

Answer (score 1):

On my machine it worked do System.setProperty("os.arch", "x86");

I am not sure that is a good idea though. ;)